# Adding Operations to Knockout Mapping Object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am struggling with adding operations to my Knockout Mapping object.

Here is where I am at right now - and I am attempting to follow the [Knockout: Mapping API information](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

This is the HTML first:

```
<a href="#" id="AddContact" class="add-button" type="button" data-bind="click: addContact">+ Add Contact</a>

<div id="ContactList">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: ContactID"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: DisplayName"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is my first attempt at wiring up Knockout:

```
var baseModel = {
    addContact: function() {
        alert('Woo!');
    }
};

contacts = ko.mapping.fromJS('[{"ContactID":6,"DisplayName":"Doe, John"},{"ContactID":7,"DisplayName":"Rogers, Mister"}]', { }, baseModel);
ko.applyBindings(contacts);
```

Now, if I remove the additional arguments ({} and `baseModel`) from the `ko.mapping.fromJS`, all my data is displayed in the table correctly. However (and as to be expected), I get a binding error with the "Add Contact" link. If I add `baseModel` back in, clicking the "Add Contact" link works, but no data displays. I get no errors one way or another, so I'm a bit stumped on what's going on there.

I'm new to KO, so I feel like I'm missing something pretty simple. I've searched across StackOverflow, but, at this point, I'm just plugging code in to see what works and not actually understanding what is happening here. Can someone provide some additional explanation and point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `ko.mapping.fromJS` but you're passing a string, not an object/array. Either use `fromJSON` or pass in a real array.

Also, you should applyBindings on baseModel, and contacts should be a field of the VM. Then you can use `foreach: contacts` instead of your weird `foreach: $root`.

See fiddle with those changes: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/kR4jc/3/

**EDIT** - Updating your answer with your code so the question can stand on its own.

JavaScript

```
var baseModel = {
    addContact: function() {
        alert('Woo!');
    }
};

baseModel.contacts = ko.mapping.fromJSON('[{"ContactID":6,"DisplayName":"Doe, John"},{"ContactID":7,"DisplayName":"Rogers, Mister"}]');

ko.applyBindings(baseModel);​
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="AddContact" class="add-button" type="button" data-bind="click: addContact">+ Add Contact</a>

<div id="ContactList">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: contacts">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: ContactID"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: DisplayName"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>​
```

Comment: The fromJS works on my actual application - I just used the JSON for the question and forgot to update. You definitely got me pointed in the right direction, so I am accepting this answer. However, after a bit more research, I decided I didn't like using the automapper (I prefer the control of doing it myself), so I went with a slightly different solution. Thanks for your help!